# How to get values of an object in json to make some operations and rebuild json with new object values?

Tags: php, json

I am calling a json data and want to make changes in values and return new json with new values by php.
for example here is the old json data:

```
[
    {
        "key": 866,
        "price": "2.4"
    },
    {
        "key": 867,
        "price": "4.3"
    }
]
```

and want to change "price" value by multiply it to a currency rate for example `2` and rebuild the json with new price values like here:

```
[
    {
        "key": 866,
        "price": "4.8"
    },
    {
        "key": 867,
        "price": "8.6"
    }
]
```

any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? The keys are completely different between the original and the new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the input, loop the items and do your work, then encode the data again using [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), something like:

```
$data = json_decode($data, true); // Convert the JSON into an associative array

// Loop the items in the array
foreach($data as $key => $item) {
    $data[$key]['price'] = $data[$key]['price'] * 1000; // Do your math here
}

echo json_encode($data); //Encode back to JSON
```

Which for the input in your question would produce the following output:

```
[
  {
    "key": 866,
    "price": 2400
  },
  {
    "key": 867,
    "price": 4300
  }
]
```